# Python function gets stuck on a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
Snapshot = {'data': []}

def SnapshotUpdater(x, side): #x is a list like [131, 18] or [135, 30]
    global Snapshot

    Rates = [x[0] for x in Snapshot['data']]

    if side == 'asks':
        for y in Snapshot['data']:
            if y[0] == x[0]:
                y[1] = x[1]
            #it still works here
            if x[0] not in Rates:
                Temp = x
                #STUCK HERE
                Snapshot['data'].append(Temp)

    print('Here')
```

`Snapshot['data']` contains the following kind of data: `[130, 12], [131, 56] ...`

To the function `SnapshotUpdater` i'm passing a list of two elements, here is an example: `[132, 20]`

What i want to do is the following: the function must check if, inside `Snapshot['data']`, there is a sublist where the first element is equal to the first element of the list i'm passing to the function. So in this case, since there isn't, the function should append to `Snapshot['data']` a new sublist `[132, 20]`. Instead, if there is already an element with the same value, just update the second value of that element with the second value of the list i passed to the function.

The problem is that, for some reason, my code gets stuck at the following line: `Snapshot['data'].append(Temp)`. I don't understand why does this happen, i tried adding `try/except` statements but i didn't get any error. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: What is `Snapshot['asks']`?

Comment: How do you know that it is stuck (as opposed to just taking a very long time to complete)?

Comment: what should this comparison accomplish?  `y[1] == x[1]`  - did you mean to set y[1]? like: `y[1] = x[1]` ?  (modifying a thing you iterate over is evil btw.)

Comment: You should not modify the thing you are looping over.

Comment: Typo when writing the question; i know it's stuck because i'm not handling huge amounts of data, just small/medium in some cases list of lists of max 20/30 elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you did not want the second `if` inside the `for` loop to actually be in the loop. In the event that `side=='asks` and `x[0] not in Rates` both evaluate to `True`, you are appending `x` to `Snapshot['data']` on every iteration, growing the list over which you are iterating. This would cause endless iteration.

Without much knowledge of what you are trying to do, does this help?

```
Snapshot = {'data': []}

def SnapshotUpdater(x, side): #x is a list like [131, 18] or [135, 30]
    global Snapshot

    Rates = [x[0] for x in Snapshot['data']]

    if side == 'asks':
        if x[0] not in Rates:
            Temp = x
            #STUCK HERE
            Snapshot['data'].append(Temp)
        else:
            for y in Snapshot['data']:
                if y[0] == x[0]:
                    y[1] = x[1]
                #it still works here


    print('Here')
```

The main thing is that `if x[0] not in Rates` evaluates to `True`, there is no point in iterating over `Snapshot['data']` and performing the same test. If you can provide a little more insight into your overall goal, maybe we can get to a better answer.

**EDIT**

Here is a solution that reflects what you mentioned in the comments:

```
Snapshot = {'data': {130:8,}} # the value for 'data' is now a dict

def SnapshotUpdater(x, side): #x is a list like [131, 18] or [135, 30]
    global Snapshot

    if side == 'asks':
        Snapshot['data'][x[0]] = x[1] # If key exists, overwrites.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried that, but still got stuck; the goal is this: if x is not on that list of lists, append it; if instead, there is an element in the list of lists in Snapshot where the first element is equal to the first element of X, just update that element in Snapshot

Comment: Ah, I understand. I would recommend using a dictionary where your first index (Rate?) is the key and the second index is the value instead of the list of lists. That way you can just insert items without regard to whether they exist already or not. I'll update my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Indeed, as you mentioned, i'm using the wrong data structure. The best way to go is to make a dictionary that looks like that {'130': 4, '153: 10, '140': 90} and so on. Now that i think about it, using a list makes no sense here